# VMM2016 and S2D doesn't allow to create HA VM

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, system-center, storage-spaces

I have deployed 2 nodes Failover Cluster with Hyper-V 2016 on top of a hyperconverged setup using S2D. The cluster managed by VMM 2016. VMM 2016 has latest UR3, Win 2016 nodes have latest Windows updates

I have two issues:

1) I can't create highly available VM using VMM. I have this error ("name" is the name of cluster, htt* ending with "p"):

> Error (2927) A Hardware Management error has occurred trying to
>   contact server 'name'  .
>
> WinRM: URL: [http://name:5985], Verb: [GET], Resource:
>   [http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wmi/root/mscluster/MSCluster_ResourceGroup?Name=SCVMM
>   wwew Resources]
>
> Unknown error (0x803381a4)
>
> Recommended Action Check that WinRM is installed and running on server
>   'name'. For more information use the command "winrm helpmsg hresult"
>   and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2742275

I can create HA VM using Failover cluster manager. The VMM agents on the hosts are in good status, all green. No errors in logs. I already did WinRM diags check, both hosts return correct response. No firewalls between nodes and VMM. Antivirus is installed, but real-time scan is off. I can add/remove hosts from/to VMM without any issues (no WinRM errors). Basically I did same setup in my lab using two VMs, it works in this configuration, I can create HA VM.

2) Very often I have status "in Maintenance" on some PD and SSD. The virtual disks are in warning status. When I run repair on them, nothing happen, 0% progess. Only help to reboot one node or rebuild VD itself, then disk status become to normal. Any ideas?

**Update 06/06/2017** - I could get some understading what's this error means:

```
winrm helpmsg 0x803381a4
```

> The WinRM client cannot process the request. A computer policy does
>   not allow the delegation of the user credentials to the target
>   computer because the computer is not trusted. The identity of the
>   target computer can be verified if you configure the WSMAN service to
>   use a valid certificate using the following command: winrm set
>   winrm/config/service @{CertificateThumbprint=""}  Or you
>   can check the Event Viewer for an event that specifies that the
>   following SPN could not be created: WSMAN/. If you find
>   this event, you can manually create the SPN using setspn.exe .  If the
>   SPN exists, but CredSSP cannot use Kerberos to validate the identity
>   of the target computer and you still want to allow the delegation of
>   the user credentials to the target computer, use gpedit.msc and look
>   at the following policy: Comp uter Configuration -> Administrative
>   Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation -> Allow Fresh
>   Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication.  Verify that it is
>   enabled and configured with an SPN appropriate for the target
>   computer. For example, for a target computer name
>   "myserver.domain.com", the SPN can be one of the following:
>   WSMAN/myserver.domain.com or WSMAN/*.domain.com. Try the request again
>   after these changes.

Basically I enabled CredSSP on my hyper-v hosts and added WSMAN to GPO as help suggests. But it didn't help.

Comment: What SSDs are you using? These aren't consumer SSDs? These aren't ones with TRIM enabled?

Comment: Does the installed antivirus have a firewall component that might be turned on?

Comment: I'm using Intel SSDSC2BA80 SSDs.All settings are default.

Comment: I tried also to uninstall AV completely, it didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following:

On the VMM and then 
Navigate to

```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager Server\Settings
```

- Change the value of BITSTcpPort from 443 to an unused port number. (i.e 8500) Reboot the VMM server after changing the value register.
- The fix might be to update all nodes to latest updates (the hotfix was included in May's or April's rollup update (don't remember which one))

And I would like to add my 0.5$ about S2D design. First,  I would recommend adding at least 2 nodes to your configuration thus you can achieve benefits from erasure coding and stop be under FT=1( this option is costly).

Comment: This s2d deployment is actually 2 nodes and they have latest May updates. I could get more details about this error, will post it in this topic.

Comment: Whatever you do, you won't build **reliable** 2-node S2D setup.

Answer (score -1):

the issue has been solved:

1. I’ve configured GPO settings on VMM Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation -> Allow Fresh Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication” with “”wsman/clusterFQDN” suffix
2. I ran this Powershell command on all Hyper-V hosts in the cluser “Enable-WSManCredSSP Server”
3. I ran this Powershell command on VMM “Enable-WSManCredSSP Client –DelegateComputer name (where name is Hyper-V host FQDN)

More info about troubleshooting steps on my blog's post: http://dmitryivakin.info/windows-server/solved-vmm-and-failover-cluster-winrm-error-0x803381a4/

Comment: S2D is royal pain in the butt to handle error conditions…